# Enquiring graduate admission on status of PhD application

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, physics, international-students

The physics PhD program at the American school I am applying to has offered early admissions, and would evaluate PhD applicants whose admission forms are completed by October 17th for Preliminary Application Review.

It has been a 10 days since the Preliminary Application Review Date, is it acceptable to contact the graduate admission in these few days to enquire on the status of the application, if the application has been rejected, pending or successful ?

Comment: If they knew already that your application has been successful or rejected, they would have informed you. The information you actually need is different. You want to know when decisions will be communicated. Which is a valid question and acceptable to ask. If you haven't received anything by that date, you can then ask if you are on a waiting list.

Comment: Thanks Roland ! you clarified my doubts ! Will email the grad admissions to enquire about the decision schedule :D

Comment: Sounds like this is resolved. I agree that asking for the decision timeline is reasonable (if you are sure this information was not already communicated to you). Though FWIW, I think expecting a decision within 10 calendar days after the deadline is not at all reasonable -- I would consider a turn-around of 1 month to be "fast".

Comment: Yes I suppose I’ll wait for a month or so before asking for a decision timeline. Thanks !